# Insertar segundo nodo delante del primero

Tags: c

Tengo un pequeño código donde quiero insertar un nodo al principio de la lista, pero se coloca después del primer nodo que ya tengo: Por ejemplo puntero primero apunta a NULL, la lista esta vacía, inserto el primer nodo con valor 5, hasta ahí todo correcto, pero al añadir un nuevo nodo con valor 7 y quedar en la visualización 75 queda al revés, 57, cuando le estoy indicando que el nuevo nodo apunte al nodo existente y éste a NULL, no entiendo porque pasa. Le dejo el código:

```
primero=NULL;
nodo1 = (t_nodo*)malloc(sizeof(t_nodo));
nodo1->dato=5;
nodo1->siguiente=NULL;
primero=nodo1;
printf("%d",nodo1->dato);

nodo2 = (t_nodo*)malloc(sizeof(t_nodo));
nodo2->dato=7;
nodo2->siguiente=nodo1;
primero=nodo2;
printf("%d",nodo2->dato);
```

Debería visualizarse primero el 7 y después el 5. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf("%d",nodo1->dato);
// ...
printf("%d",nodo2->dato);
```

Ese codigo está mostrando los elementos sin importar su orden en la lista.

Lo que tienes que hacer es iterar la lista después de rellenarla e imprimir los valores que te encuentres

```
t_nodo* ptr = primero;

while( ptr )
{
  printf("%d",ptr->dato);
  ptr = ptr->siguiente;
}
```